# How i assigne string to variable in shorthand if statement?

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors, c-strings, conditional-operator

in this example I want if the condition is true, the NAME value to be jack

```
int main(){
    char NAME[6];
    NAME = (4 < 5 ) ? "jack" : "Linda";
}
```

But when i compile it encounter this error:

*::: assignment to expression with array type*

Comment: There's a few problems with what you're trying to do. But first, you should look into using the `string.h` library, specifically `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. Use standard string function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>` to copy a string in an array.

That is you need to write

```
#include <string.h>

int main( void ){
    char NAME[6];
    strcpy( NAME, (4 < 5 ) ? "jack" : "Linda" );
}
```